# SQL Server Irish FADA not displaying correctly

Tags: sql-server

In SQL by default it was using `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS`
From my backup SQL DB, I change collation into `Latin1_General_100_CI_AS_SC_UTF8`

[image: Collation]

However when I query, the text show as An Phr�omhsr�id Uachtarach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the collation of an existing database doesn't change the collation of existing objects within it, only new ones.  For existing tables you'll need to update the collation on each table column separately.

```
ALTER TABLE MyTable
ALTER COLUMN MyCol VARCHAR(100) COLLATE Latin1_General_100_CI_AS_SC_UTF8;
```

Note that could be a blocking operation which could be an issue in large tables.  To get around that you can create a new table with the correct collation, copy the data in, delete the old table, and rename the new table to the old name.

Comment: Thankyou, I have tried a couple FADA text and was working correctly. It seems python code wasn't run with utf-8 inserting datas

Comment: Bah, yep, that'll do it too.  GIGO.